# Spring MVC as a REST provider with AngularJS vs JSP/Velocity/Freemarker for the web layer

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

Creators of Spring MVC by default recommend using JSP or one of the template engines (Freemarker, Velocity) to provide the web layer.

On the other hand, the supporters of JavaScript frameworks would probably recommend using Spring MVC only as a REST/WS service provider and decouple completely the service layer from the web layer which would be created in one of the JS frameworks (e.g. Angular JS).

Does the latter solution has any drawbacks comparing to the former one?
Is one of the approaches considered right now as an up-to-date industry standard?

Comment: stop thinking so much about recommendations. think about what *your use case* demands. Of course there are drawbacks to introducing an *entire new* (very large) *framework* to your application architecture (a lot of intellectual overhead, for one) - and of course there are benefits (the ability to execute your view logic client-side, for one). the question is whether *you* need the benefits / can afford the overhead

Comment: @drewmoore Isn't it true that one of the advantages of the latter approach is the decoupling of the view layer from the service layer and as a result having a better starting point to create mobile apps using the same service layer?

Comment: decoupling is not a question of what framework(s) you're using, it's about the quality of your code and design practices in *whatever* framework(s) you're using. Using a JS framework on the front-end is going to *force* you to separate your view logic from your model/service logic now, but they can and should be equally well-separated if you do the whole thing with Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the later one has a drawback comparing to the former is only that by using latter you drive your application to some complexity level, which I think you don't want in the first place.

Complexity examples are like you will do create some template and will end up with creating an application which is not SEO friendly, so to remove this you will include some another technology into your stack. Second one will give you some real scope to make you app awesome  using SPA architecture but will at some cost. But here in contrast the first one probably make your work much easier to develop but at much more network bandwidth cost. So to me its your choice which fits you, either you wanna make it done easily and pay higher to your hosting provider or make some hard work, maximize your efficiency and minimize your cost.

But yes when you are following the up-to-date industry standard then its obvious to go with the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on your requirements. With Javascript frameworks like AngularJS you get MVC on the client side, you need to write javascript controllers whereas with Spring MVC you get the MVC architecture on the server side.

AngularJS is primarily used for developing Single Page Applications which involve heavy DOM manipulation. So VC part of MVC would be written in javascript & would load just once.

In my opinion there is no revolutionary difference between the two. You should proceed with what you are comfortable with.